# Re-loop until all matches are found, logic?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, glob

I cannot figure out the logic for this. I am attempting to compare a list of matches 'matches' to files from a folder. If file in 'folders' equal the name in 'matches', then do something, but obviously it doesn't 'try' each match to each file. I'm thinking I need to use a while loop but I don't know how to apply it.

```
import os
import glob
import os.path

folders = glob.glob('C:\\Corrections\\*.*')
matches = open('filename.txt', 'r')

for each in folders:
    splitname_one = each.split('\\', 3)   #Separate the filename from the path
    filename = splitname_one[3]           #Get Filename only
    basefile = filename.split('.', 1)     #Separate filename and file extension
    compare0 = basefile[0]                #assign base file name to compare0
    #print (basefile[0])
    for line in matches:
        match = line.split('.', 1)        #Separe base filename from file extension
        #print (match[1])
        compare1 = match[0]               #assign base file name to compare1
        if compare1==compare0:
            #os.rename(filename, 'C:\\holder\\' + filename)
            print ('We Have a match!')
        else:
            print ('no match :( ')
```

Comment: Your outer loop loops over the file object each time.  When the file reaches EOF the first time you loop through it, subsequent passes through your outer loop won't do anything because there are no lines left in `matches`.  Just do `matches = open(...).readlines()` or something.

FYI if you want to get just the filename or directory parts of a path you can use `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.basename`.  You can also split file extension with `os.path.splitext`  Your current code will break if a filename `contains.multiple.dots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW here's how I might end up doing something like this:

```
import glob
from os.path import basename, splitext

def file_base(filename):
    return splitext(basename(filename))[0]

folders = set(file_base(f) for f in glob.glob('C:\\Corrections\\*.*'))

with open('filename.txt') as fobj:
    matches = set(file_base(f) for f in fobj.readlines())

print(folders.intersection(matches))
```

Comment: I will review this and comment back, I like to understand what each part of the code does even if it works :) Thank you.